# Ansible Setting fact with dynamic key/value

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to set ansible facts from the stdout of a command task I call from another role.

**Role A:**

```
- name: example command
  command: client get -s {{ service }}
  register: vars_string

- name: set vars
  set_fact: vars={{ vars_string.stdout.split('\n')}}
  when:
    - vars_string.stdout | length > 0

- name: set vars as facts
  set_fact: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ vars }}"
```

**vars output:**

```
"vars": [
        "tst=ansible", 
        "example=values"
]
```

**Role B:**

```
- debug:
    var: tst
```

**Results from Role B:**

Expectation: `{ "tst": "ansible" }`

Reality: `{ "tst": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!" }`

I have tried to spit vars into a dict and use `set_fact: "{{ item.key }}" : "{{ item.value }}"` as well. This returned the same results.

I want to be able to call by the variable name returned from the command in future roles. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points about your code snippet that may interest you:

- There is already a split-by-newline version of the output from your command, it's `vars_string.stdout_lines`
- I can't tell if you just chose that variable by accident, or you were trying to actually *assign* to the `vars` built-in variable, but either way, don't do that

---

As best I can tell, there is no supported syntax for assigning arbitrary top-level host facts from within just a task.

You have two choices: write out those variables to a file, then use [`include_vars:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/include_vars_module.html) to read them in -- which will assign them as host facts, or concede to the way `set_fact:` wants things and be content with those dynamic variables living underneath a known key in hostfacts

We'll show the latter first, because it's shorter:

```
- set_fact:
    my_facts: >-
      {{ "{" + (vars_string.stdout_lines
      | map('regex_replace', '^([^=]+)=(.+)', '"\1": "\2"')
      | join(",")) + "}"
      }}
  when:
  - vars_string.stdout | length > 0
```

Of course, be aware that trickery won't work if your keys or values have non-JSON friendly characters in them, but if that simple version doesn't work, ask a follow-up question, because there are a lot more tricks in that same vein

The `include_vars:` way is:

```
- tempfile:
    state: file
    suffix: .json
  register: vars_filename

- copy:
    dest: '{{ vars_filename.path }}'
    content: >-
       {{ "{" + (vars_string.stdout_lines
       | map('regex_replace', '^([^=]+)=(.+)', '"\1": "\2"')
       | join(",")) + "}"
       }}

- include_vars:
    file: '{{ vars_filename.path }}'

- file:
    path: '{{ vars_filename.path }}'
    state: absent
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to add one step in between copy and include_vars. It was searching on the localhost for the vars_filename.path when it was on the remote host. I added fetch and it worked.

Comment: Or you can add `delegate_to: localhost` for all those actions and they'll take place on `localhost`, saving you the network round-trip(s) as well as the `fetch:`

Answer (score 0):

*I have tried to spit vars into a dict and use set_fact: "{{ item.key }}" : "{{ item.value }}" as well. This returned the same results.*

I've done something similar with

```
set_fact: "{{ item.key }}"="{{ item.value }}"
```

Not sure if it's a new thing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35577119)